# Call nifi processor as a rest api

Tags: pyspark, apache-nifi

I want to call a Nifi custom processor as a REST Api and pass the parameters at run-time through pyspark. And retrieve the results in the response object.
Can anyone please help me in suggesting different approaches for the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the following sequence of processors:

- `HandleHttpRequest`
- extract patameters
- your other processors...
- prepare response
- `HandleHttpResponse`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please tell me the ways of passing different datatypes such as dict , list along with pandas dataframe as input parameters for the pyspark job in the nifi rest api template?

Comment: about pyspark better to ask a separate question with exact problem you have. the `HandleHttpRequest` processor will accept any data format from your http request and put it as a flowfile content. and how you'll process this content in pyspark it's another question.

Comment: daggett , could you please tell me how to handle a json post request made to the HandleHttpRequest?

Comment: just after `HandleHttpRequest` you'll have json in flowfile content that you've posted to nifi. What is your question about? How to parse json? Or whole flow example?

Comment: I am currently getting a zero byte file from the flow-file when i use a putFile instead of the json parameters posted to the handlehttp request processor

Comment: what do you use to  `POST` json to nifi?

Comment: I am using requests library from python. 
import requests
requests.post("http://localhost:6202/sample",json={"id":1,"name":"test"})

Answer (score 1):

The steps are:

1. Configure [HandleHttpRequest](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.7.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.HandleHttpRequest/) processor.
2. Enable the required HTTP methods (GET, POST, DELETE, etc.).
3. Set the listening port.

[image]

4. Attached the Context Map to a service (the listener).

[image]
5. Enable the service and the processor.

Bonus:
If you run Nifi from a Docker container, as I do, you should get the container's IP:

`docker inspect <container-name> --format='{{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress}}'`

Now, you can run Postman, and the HandleHttpRequest processor will fetch it. For example:

[image]

I created a simple template to exemplify this scenario. The HTTP request's body is saved into a directory:

[image]